# Request parameter is null?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am having trouble receiving a simple JSON request with ASP.NET Core 5. For whatever reason, it is not binding my JSON and passing it into the parameter in the action.

Here is my json:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 31,
    "city": "New York"
}
```

Here is my controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubtractCurrency([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    return Json(data);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Currently I am just trying to print the entire data out, but it is just null. I can easily send a request with a simple string and receive like a string and that works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using JSON.NET for serialization or System.Text.Json (default)?

Comment: P.S. I removed your `[.net]` (.NET Framework) tag and replaced it with the `[.net-5]` one.

Comment: You're using old  (pre .net core 3) style json objects.  [The answer is here](https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/05/10/why-model-binding-to-jobject-from-a-request-doesnt-work-anymore-in-asp-net-core-3-1-and-whats-the-alternative/)

Comment: @JHBonarius You can still use `JObject`, etc. even in .NET 5, provided that you configure the correct serializer.

Comment: Thanks all - what should i use instead of JObject? Basically i just want to convert all the json to a key value list somehow? i don't need to model-bind it to a custom class

Comment: You should bind to a model class or a dictionary. That is the way to go.

Comment: Ah yeah a dictionary of course - but i am not sure how to accomplish this? Can you provide an example or redirect me to a place that does? thanks again man

Comment: Why dont you just make a `class Person` with those attributes and declare your controller method to take a Person? You don't even have to type anything yourself, just paste the Json into http://QuickType.io and it'll make the class for you

Comment: I see - but is that the way you should always do it? I mean, what if i wanted to pass in some JSON data that doesn't really translate well into an object? In this case a Person class makes sense, but what if i wanted to pass something more arbitrary like i wanted to edit a persons city - it would have a person object with a prop that says "new-city" as well? That just seems off to me. but maybe i'm thinking about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

`System.Text.Json`, the default JSON Serializer/Deserializer from .Net Core 3.0 cannot parse JSON to JToken (like JObject, JArray) through the request body directly.

You can change it back to `Newtonsoft.Json` instead

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` in NuGet
2. Go to `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup.cs`
3. Add `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` after the `services.AddControllers()`

Result: `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`
[image: result]